# Fortify Incremental Scan: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, fortify

I am following these steps for Fortify incremental scan

Step 1 :clean => sourceanalyzer -b my-forty-project-ain -clean

Step 2 : Translation => sourceanalyzer -Xmx12G -b my-forty-project-ain -source 1.8  equipment/**/*.java

Step 3 : First Scan => sourceanalyzer -Xmx12G -b my-forty-project-ain -scan -incremental-base -f 
results_ain.fpr

Step 4 : We do changes to the code

Step 5 : Translation again => sourceanalyzer -Xmx12G -b my-forty-project-ain -source 1.8  equipment/**/*.java

Step 6 : Incremental Scal => sourceanalyzer -Xmx12G -b my-forty-project-ain -scan -incremental -f results_ain.fpr

I am getting following error in step 6

An error occurred while initializing the scan engine.
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of com.fortify.sca.util.serialization.SCARuleHandle to field com.fortify.sca.metadata.SingletonMeta.rule of type com.fortify.sca.rules.SCAGlobalClassRule in instance of com.fortify.sca.metadata.SingletonMeta
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2287) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1417) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2293) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.readObject(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1445) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2178) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at com.fortify.sca.backend.BackEnd.loadProgramModel(BackEnd.java:1173) ~[fortify-sca-19.2.0.0196.jar:?]
    at com.fortify.sca.backend.BackEnd.initializeEngine(BackEnd.java:575) [fortify-sca-19.2.0.0196.jar:?]
    at com.fortify.sca.backend.BackEnd.analyze(BackEnd.java:776) [fortify-sca-19.2.0.0196.jar:?]
    at com.fortify.sca.Main$Sourceanalyzer.run(Main.java:717) [fortify-sca-19.2.0.0196.jar:?]

Comment: I'm running into the same issue now. Were you able to fix this?